How to disbale auto indent on key press on an empty line in Intellij IDEA?
Intellij IDEA applies auto indentation on empty lines.

For example, this:
••••thing.method()
••••••••

Becomes this after I insert a dot character:
••••thing.method()
••••.

And here's what I want to happen:
••••thing.method()
••••••••.

(• represents the whitespace)

How do I disable this feature? I've disabled the "Smart indent", but it didn't help.
I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.1

Here's what it looks like in action:


Question: will it format as you wish if you type the whole thing and then invoke the built-in formatter (on that block)? If it does not -- then I'd check the Code Style settings.

@LazyOne Changing the built-in formatter's settings fixed this. (continuation indent) Can you post an answer so I could accept it?

It was just a thought (educated one, but still). Better you post the answer with exact changes in settings that resolved your issue.

What I needed to do was to change the value of the Continuation indent option in Editor > Code Style > Java.
The formatter options are being applied as you type.



Thanks to LazyOne.
